# Modified Matching with priority

Tags: algorithm, graph, bipartite

Let there be N such hotels which want to hire a cook and N such cooks which are searching for job.So, after conducting the interviews each hotel has prepared its own ordered list of cooks according to their preferance and similarly, every cook has also prepared a ordered list of hotels according to his/her preference. Now, we are given prefrence list of all hotels and cooks, and we need to calculate how many hotels and cooks get their first preference.

Example : Let say we have N=4 and preferance list of Hotels in decreasing order is as follow :

1 2 3 4

2 3 4 1

4 2 3 1

1 3 2 4

Similarly preferance list of cooks is as follows :

1 2 3 4

4 3 2 1

4 2 3 1

4 1 2 3

Now here 1 Hotel will get his first prefernce cook and 2 cooks will get their prefered hotel.

I need to find the count of these hotels and cooks both that get their first prefered option

Comment: Why are the second/third etc. choices relevant at all?